# Is a pathological-liar a genuine behavior disorder? How is it different than a compulsive-liar, habitual-liar, and a sociopath?

Tags: behavior, sociopath

Is a "pathological-liar" a genuine behavior disorder? How is it different than a "compulsive-liar," "habitual-liar," and a "sociopath"? What are the differences in terminology?

Comment: +1 for a good, interesting question, _and_ you will receive the best (most accurate, most comprehensive) answers if you _share the research you've done_ to find answers. _See:_ [How do I ask a good question?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)